# Display component from within provider

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular `Component` called `<confetti></confetti>`.
The HTML and CSS for this include confetti animation. Now this works perfectly if I hard-code the confetti html tag directly in any page I want.

However, what I need to do is to inject the `<confetti>` tag dynamically to whichever currently active page from a `provider` that has an observable running every x seconds.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try to put confetti component in top of components(app.component.html) and connect it to service which will you call whenever you want animation to pop up? The second option could be to dynamically create component.

Comment: How will I connect it? Using `@ViewChild` ?

Comment: You can probably use a [dynamic component](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loader) for this.

Comment: To connect it lets introduce `ConfettiService` which you will call and in `ConfettiComponent` you will subscribe to some Subject/Observable(from that service) and react(turn on animation).